# Linq2SQL to produce Like operator

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-like

I have a string "Word1 Word2" and I want to transform it to a query such as "Like '%Word1%Word2%'".

At the moment I have:

```
from t in Test
where t.Field.Contains("Word1 Word2")
```

How to do this in LINQ2SQL? Do I need to create two separate queries for this, can't I write it in the same statement?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from t in Test
where SqlMethods.Like(t.Field, "%Word1%Word2%")
select t
```

Comment: Although the others may be correct, I preferred this solution.

Comment: That's nice, didnt know this method. It's generating this exactly, if someone wondered : 
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(13) SET @p0 = '%Word1%Word2%'  .....  
WHERE [t0].[Name] LIKE @p0

Answer (score 0):

Well that would translate to

```
LIKE "%Word1 Word2%"
```

which is probably not what you want... If you write your query like this:

```
where t.Field.Contains("Word1") && t.Field.Contains("Word2")
```

It will generate the following SQL :

```
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(4) SET @p0 = '%ab%'
DECLARE @p1 VarChar(4) SET @p1 = '%cd%'
....
SELECT ...
WHERE ([t0].[Field] LIKE @p0) AND ([t0].[Field] LIKE @p1)
```

Comment: The original `LIKE` only matches when both words appear in the field.

Answer (score 0):

As work-around, maybe this will suffice:

```
from t in Test
where t.Field.Contains("Word1") && t.Field.Contains("Word2")
```

...with some post-filtering on the client side, to ensure that word2 comes after word1.